# In circuit debugging using continuity test on DMM give un-predictable results

Tags: resistance, continuity

I did a continuity test, between a ground point of my PCI card (audio) and a resistance (47Ω SMD). No beeping sound on both ends of the resistance.
After I de-soldered the resistance from the board, I received a beeping  on one end of the mounting metal plate (where the resistance was soldered).
Can somebody explain, what exactly could have produced this behavior?
An example diagram would be the best for me to understand.

[image]

Comment: Did you check carefully for a solder splash or bridge from your de-soldering that's shorting the pad to ground? In-circuit resistance tests can sometimes fool you due to non-linear junctions and capacitances.

Comment: You tried continuity test on an unknown circuit and it did not beep. Then you changed the circuit by removing a resistor and it beeped. You don't know what the circuit that you are probing does and how it works and you also don't know how your meter determines when to beep or not to beep. We can't draw a diagram of your sound card as we don't know what resistors there are, what they do and which one you removed. It would be easier if you posted photos or diagrams what you did.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is very simple. Here is the explanation I gave previously to someone else with a very similar issue: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/676251

In short, your measurement are invalid. You can't measure in circuit resistance.

Edit: Since you improve your question, I'll improve my answer!
How does the continuity works on a DMM. There are more then one way they operate, but the most common one is, just like the diode, a constant current source that when the voltage drops bellow a certain value, it beeps. So, on the strange behavior, when it doesn't beep, that means that the voltage on the terminal don't get low enough. Your schematic is clearly oversimplifying and the reason it doesn't beep is hidden there. There is no faulty component in parallel that would prevent a short in DC. So that measurement is invalid.

On the next one, it could beep for a number of reason. One of them is that you are powering your circuit, or that a component failed due to the higher then rated current.

Basically, beep beep test should be ONLY used when you have a bare board. Any thing else will create odd behavior because you can't predict how semiconductors will behave while not powered. Never debug any circuit with an ohm meter or beep beep. It's a bad practice that beginner often use and lead them to false conclusions.

You should power the board and measure the behavior with voltage and current, not ohms.

Comment: The resistance is 47Ω. My multi-meter gives a beep on resistance lower than 30Ω.  If i understand your explanation, it means that when i made the first continuity test between GND and the end of the resistance that connected to the ground, multi-meter must have being beeping (because the wire which connect the resistance end with GND has less than 30Ω resistance) but because there are active components in the card, the Ohm's low R=V/I , does not give the right result (<30 Ω), because the Volt provided by multi-meter (and used by it in the calculation of R) is not the one that have produce...

Comment: that have produce the Current that the multi-meter measure (in order to use it in the calculator of R), because there are several amplifications due to existence of active components (the same if the multi-meter provide current and measure Volt) ?
But how this can explain the continuity test, after i have removed the resistance from the board ? Why, then i have a beeping between the GND and the one metallic pad ? Does not happen the same "missunderstanding" from the multi-meter due to the existance of active components that amplify the currents or Volt ?

Comment: Sorry. I added my two previous comments before i read your new edit. Now i have no time to read it. When i will read it, and if you have already answered my last comments i will delete them.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The behavior you are seeing is indeed unpredictable because you are using a function of a DMM that CAN'T be used in circuit. Any result it will give you will be trash. You should NEVER use a ohm-meter or continuity tester with semiconductor components. In circuit debug can ONLY be done with a voltmeter or ammeter. Any other function will give you unpredictable results.

Comment: I could figure out why your DMM beep, but what's the point! I will only find the reason why it's invalid! Just the polarity of your probe could make it beep or not!

Comment: In fact, i did make a Volt measurement. I "inject" 3V in the board and measured the potential difference between the ends of every component i could on the board, i think all of them (they must be more than 100 or 150). And i did this because as i had removed several components (10 tantalum caps, 2 electrolytic capacitors,4 voltage regulators etc) i made the beeping test between the two mounting metallic plates (on the board were these components should placed, without the components detached to them) , and gave me continuously beeping, so assume that there was a short somewhere (please c...

Comment: (please confirm that this is right).
From all the 100 - 200 components, only five do not gave any indication of Voltage. Then i, also, made the continuity test between GND and these five components and gave no beeping. When i removed the first of these five (the 47Ω SMD resistor) i had Voltage meassurement on one of its mounting plate on the board and also have beeping. The rest four components did not affect from this action. But when i removed the second of them (a four SMD resistor array of 150Ω) not only have Volt measurement and beeping on its mounting plate on board, but also on the...

Comment: but also on the rest three of them (a four SMD resistor array of 150Ω, too) without remove them.
That is why in my first question i talk about continuity. Because i believed that if i have no Volt measurement, then it means that current do not flow through the component i have measured and that is why i also have not a beeping.
But first i must know about the confirmation i am asking in the end of the first paragraph.

Comment: After i read your answer, except from the beeping test i also measured the resistance and gave me again strange results. I did this between the two mounting plates of the two electrolytic caps (without them be on the board). Multi-meter beeping in diode mode, but when i measure the resistance it gives me 5 kΩ the first cap and 1,5 the second. Same result when measure between GND and the + mounting plate.
How this can happen ? I mean, if my Multi-meter's specification is to beeping when resistance <30Ω, how it beeps when resistance is 1500Ω or 5000Ω ?

Comment: I'll say it one last time. YOU CAN'T MAKE RESISTANCE, DIODE OR CONTINUITY MEASUREMENT IN CIRCUIT. Your questions is why you are reading garbage in those mode, the answer is that you can't make those measurements in circuit. The semiconductors on the board are messing up with your measurements. If you don't believe me, measure the resistance of a diode, reverse the probes and measure it again, then add a resistance in parallel,  you will see, they don't behave as you expect.